# RoR field set on form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you add a field set to a form_for method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `field_set_tag`. For example, using a generic 'user' object

For Rails 2.3.x

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <% field_set_tag 'Name' do %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

And for Rails 3.0.0:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= field_set_tag 'Name' do %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: is that supposed to be <%= f.text_field %>?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a new object or get an existing object from your dc since it is a 'form for' and then you create a form builder `f` and call methods on that form builder such as the following:

```
<% form_for(@object) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :method_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so something like
<%= f.field_set 'test' %>